# This angular 10 stackblitz still requires entryComponents

Tags: angular

I just tried to cleanup an angular 10 stackblitz by removing the `entryComponents`, but that broke the whole app

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ TestComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const customElement = createCustomElement(TestComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('test-ce', customElement);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() { }
}
```

[The stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-custom-elements-lwk8rz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Any suggestions what the reason might be that this property is still needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why entryComponents is not necessary anymore in Angular 9/ivy compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541876/why-entrycomponents-is-not-necessary-anymore-in-angular-9-ivy-compiler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enable Ivy first

[image]

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-custom-elements-rshz6l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**

Comment: Also see https://www.newline.co/@NishuGoel/bye-bye-entrycomponents--3f4bd4eb

Comment: @JanosVinceller See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541876/why-entrycomponents-is-not-necessary-anymore-in-angular-9-ivy-compiler/61548510#61548510

Comment: I tagged the question as a duplicate therefore.

Comment: the question is not why entryComponents is deprecated, its about why this stackblitz example still needs it.