# Angular production mode entryComponents not quite working

Tags: angular

I am using a [custom attribute solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114267) and a [dynamic component creation](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d) in order to create components dynamically. The component is decorated with a custom attribute and then looked up in a dictionary at runtime. Such components have to be referenced in the module with `entryComponents`. This is working fine in dev mode but as soon as I try production, it no longer works.

There are no errors/warning in the build process either. Things just stop working. There is a `@deprecated` comment for `entryComponents` telling that it is no longer necessary but apparently not wrong to use.

Even if I move the `entryComponents` into the `app.module.ts`, the prod mode still fails. How can I make this work? I am happy to use other methods as long as I can reference components by name at runtime.

I have created [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/entry-component-bug) that reproduces the problem along with [a git repository](https://github.com/stigun/entry-component-bug). Please note that merely doing `enableProdMode()` in StackBlitz will not demonstrate the issue. You have to do the "--prod" which I am not sure StackBlitz can do.

When running the app with `ng serve` all is fine but trying the production mode with `ng serve --prod` makes the app behave differently.

Comment: Please elaborate the issue which are facing. Behave differently is a very generic term.

Comment: There is an unexpected and different behavior between dev and prod build. I explained the difference. Apparently `entryComponents` works in the dev build but gets completely ignored in the prod build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Like you, I have a dynamic component with a custom decorator.

Even though the component is imported in the Module and referenced in `declarations` the decorator is not executed. The reason, if I understand correctly, is tree-shaking.

The solution is simple:

```
// my.module.ts
import { MyDynamicComponent } from './my-dynamic.component.ts';

const dynamicComponents = [MyDynamicComponent];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...dynamicComponents],
    imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

If you are having this problem within a library compiled with ng-packager, the solution above is not enough, you also have to "use" the variable somehow.

For example:

```
// my.module.ts
import { MyDynamicComponent } from './my-dynamic.component.ts';

const dynamicComponents = [MyDynamicComponent];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...dynamicComponents],
    imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class MyModule {
    constructor() {
        (window as any).dynamicComponents = dynamicComponents;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I ended up doing but forgot to answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Angular 9+. As the error says entryComponents is deprecated since Angular 9 and implementation of Ivy, so you can safely remove it. Also you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541876/why-entrycomponents-is-not-necessary-anymore-in-angular-9-ivy-compiler) and [here](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2020/02/07/what-is-new-angular-9.0/)

Comment: This wont solve the issue. The problem appears with the custom decorator in prod mode